# Is repeatedly setting an img src attribute with a base64 data: URL a reasonable way to animate based on server generated images?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple need for a preview of image data that is updated regularly in realtime on the server side.  The server can easily generate Base64 encoded JPEG images.  I have JavaScript that fetches the current data and sets the src attribute of an image.

This appears to work fine when testing with the server running locally (i.e. URLs are to localhost), however it seems that when client and server are on different machines, after some time the browser gets bogged down and can't handle it anymore.   It seems like old image data is hanging around and getting garbage collected or something similar is causing a slow down and ultimately a failure to reliably update the image on the browser side.

Here is the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Live Stream</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <img id="img1" width="320" height="180" src="data:," />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fetching = false;

const fetchImage = async () => {
    fetching = true;
    try {
        const response = await fetch(document.baseURI+'app/image/base64');
        var frame = await response.text();
        document.getElementById("img1").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+frame;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    fetching = false;
}

function updateImage() {
    fetchImage();
}

window.requestAnimationFrame( draw );

function draw(timestamp) {
    if( !fetching ) {
        updateImage();
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame( draw );
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way?  Low-latency is important.

I also have an alternative that uses WebSockets to push data.  That might make more sense with the data rate is lower. Either way, the display of the data is handled the same way. by updating the src of an  with a new 'data:' URL.

Comment: Why would you want to re-draw an image 60 times a second? Use a `<video>` element and stream a video

Comment: @Andreas Because streaming a live video is much more difficult and has poor browser support.  I can get video.js to make HLS work in non-Apple browsers, but the latency is very high.  WebRTC was a consideration, until I looked into it deeply and saw that there is basically no support at all for streaming from a server.  The existing libraries are very complex because WebRTC is based on solving browser-to-browser video streaming and does not address the easier problem of server to browser streaming.